# Brief glitch on The Workplace main page

Tags: bug, status-norepro

A couple of minutes ago, the [front page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) of the main site showed all the normal header and sidebar stuff, but no questions. I refreshed and re-opened the page several times, and it didn't help.

The problem went away on its own. The problem doesn't appear to have lasted more than a few minutes.

As of Sat 2013-02-09 02:25:55 UTC, I'm seeing the problem again -- and it just went away again.

Comment: I got a similar problem at the same time, except i got a page saying, sorry the site is having problems as such it is only in read only mode, or something to that effect

Comment: @RhysW: If you ran into that in the last few hours, it's a different issue, caused by the migration to the New York data center. I saw the missing questions problem before that migration started.

Comment: It was a result of the data center move, network wide temporary outages: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166885/sites-tags-are-intermittently-devoid-of-questions

Comment: @Rarity: I *thought* it happened before the move started, but I could be mistaken (and it's probably not worth exploring further unless it happens again).

Answer (score 1):

This was transient during the migration between data centers.